# What does it really mean for a Lagrangian to be independent of the base coordinates?

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, fiber-bundles, euler-lagrange-equation, jet-bundles

In this question I will be considering what is called in physics a "classical Lagrangian field theory" from a geometric point of view.

One is given an $n$ dimensional (smooth, real) "spacetime manifold" $M$, with some "field" $\psi$ on it. From a purely local point of view, the field is assumed to have components $\psi^i(x)$. A (first-order) Lagrangian is then an $n$-form $$ \hat L=\mathcal L(\{x^\mu\},\{\psi^i(x)\},\{\partial_\mu\psi^i(x)\})dx^1\wedge...\wedge dx^n $$ that depends on the field, the field derivatives and maybe on the spacetime coordinates explicitly.

In physics, it is considered pathological for a Lagrangian to depend explicitly on the spacetime coordinates. Usually it signals a "nonclosed" system, where there are externally imposed fields, whose dynamics are not controlled by a Lagrangian.

---

From a more precise point of view, let $E\rightarrow M$ be a rank $k$ vector bundle over $M$ (it can be a general fiber bundle, and in fact, it is often *not* a vector bundle, but even in those cases, one can often consider it a vector bundle - for example the bundle of metrics, which is nonlinear may be enlarged to the bundle of symmetric (0,2) tensors, which is).

The field $\psi$ is considered a section of $E$. In a local trivialization $E$ has coordinates $(\{x^\mu\},\{y^i\})$.

We can consider the first jet bundle $J^1E$ of (sections of) $E$, whose local coordinates are $(\{x^\mu\},\{y^i\},\{y^i_\mu\})$.

If $\psi$ is a section of $E$, it "looks like" in local coordinates as $$\psi: x\mapsto (\{x^\mu\},\{\psi^i(x)\}), $$ and its *first jet prolongation* $j^1\psi$ looks like as $$ j^1\psi:x\mapsto (\{x^\mu\},\{\psi^i(x)\},\{\partial_\mu\psi^i(x)\}).$$

The (first-order) Lagrangian is then a horizontal $n$-form on $J^1E$, which in a local trivialization looks like as $$ \hat L=\mathcal L(\{x^\mu\},\{y^i\},\{y^i_\mu\})dx^1\wedge...\wedge dx^n $$ where the $dx^\mu$ are considered 1-forms on $J^1E$.

The fields are not involved here, however, the *action functional* is defined as $$ S[\psi]=\int (j^1\psi)^\ast\hat L, $$ where $$(j^1\psi)^*\hat L=\mathcal L(\{x^\mu\},\{\psi^i(x)\},\{\partial_\mu\psi^i(x)\})dx^1\wedge...\wedge dx^n.$$

**The problem:**

It is a well known fact that if $E\rightarrow M$ is some fiber bundle (like the $E$ previously defined, *or* $J^1E$), then if $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is some smooth function (the target space of this map is not really relevant), and in some local trivialization this function looks like as $$ f(\{y^i\}), $$ eg. $f$ doesn't depend on the base coordinates $x^\mu$, then this is not a trivialization-independent statement. In some other trivialization, it will look like as $$ f^\prime(\{x^{\prime\mu}\},\{y^{\prime i}\}). $$

On the other hand, as I have stated in the beginning of the question, in physics it is considered pathological to have a Lagrangian that depends explicitly on $x^\mu$. However by the previous argument, it should not be possible to construct a Lagrangian on $J^1E$, that looks like $$ \hat L=\mathcal L(\{y^i\},\{y^i_\mu\}) $$ in *all* trivializations.

Now, I know that in physics, there is often a lot of background structure assumed. These background structures can break "general covariance". I can illustrate this with the following example: For the massless Klein-Gordon field in Minkowski-spacetime, the Lagrangian (in physics language - so this is already pulled back via the field's prolongation) is $$ \mathcal L=\frac{1}{2}\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\psi\partial_\nu\psi\ dx^1\wedge...dx^n, $$ where $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ is the canonical "flat" form of the dual Lorentz-metric. It is not explicitly $x$-dependent, but this is not a trivialization-independent statement. If we perform a non-Poincaré coordinate transformation, the Lagrangian will look like $$ \mathcal L=\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}(x)\partial_\mu\psi\partial_\nu\psi\sqrt{|\det g(x)|}dx^1\wedge...dx^n. $$

Here the general form of the metric $g_{\mu\nu}(x)$ is $x$-dependent, but is an externally imposed field, so the Lagrangian **is** $x$-dependent.

However, in physics, if we account for everything, then we can get rid of all background structures. For example, we can consider the gravitational field (the metric) $g$, a matter field $\psi$ (a Dirac field, or a scalar multiplet), and a gauge connection $A$, and mesh everything into a glorious Lagrangian $$ \mathcal L(\psi,\partial\psi,A,\partial A,g,\partial g,\partial\partial g) $$ (this Lagrangian will be second order in $g$, but that doesn't change the problem).

Now, this Lagrangian will never acquire explicit $x$-dependence, through either diffeomorphisms of $M$, or changes of trivialization in $E$ (here $\psi$ is a section of $E$, and $E$ is considered a $G$-bundle for some Lie group $G$, and $A$ is a $G$-connection) or for that matter, in the "connection bundle" in which $A$ lives.

So from this, it seems to me that if we use fiber products to create one massive fiber bundle $\mathcal E$ from all these bundles involved, then the unified Lagrangian is still a horizontal element in $\Omega^n(J^1\mathcal E)$, yet it will never acquire explicit $x$-dependence.

**Question:**

Considering all the lengthy exposition I have given above, how do you invariantly and geometrically characterize Lagrangians which do not depend explicitly on the base manifold's coordinates? Since this should be a trivialization-dependent statement, yet it also seems to be that it is possible to construct Lagrangians that absolutely do not depend on any background structures, and are as such $x$-independent.

Comment: Nice question. One possible answer could be found ni the theory of natural bundles and natural operators: I think the purest notion of such an "invariant" Lagrangian would be one that arises as a natural operator $F \to \Omega^n,$ where $F$ is some natural bundle functor (e.g. sending $M$ to your $\mathcal E$ over $M$) and $\Omega^n$ sends $M^n$ to $\Lambda^n  T^* M.$

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I'm not sure. I have only a very small knowledge of natural bundles (once read through Michor/Kolár/Slovák, but not deeply), however in physics, the likely principal bundle of symmetries is $SF(M)\times P_1\times P_2\times P_3$ where $SF(M)$ is the spin-frame bundle and the rest are $U(1)$, $SU(2)$ and $SU(3)$ principal bundles. All fields are expected to be sections of associated bundles of these. I can imagine $SF:M\mapsto SF(M)$ be a functor on the category of Lorentz manifolds with spin structure (if this is a category even), but not the other three.

Comment: I know very little of the physics, so I might be way off base. That being said, some googling turned up [*Gauge-Natural Bundles and Generalized Gauge Theories*](https://goo.gl/t3pGTb), which makes a (superficially) similar definition to the one I proposed; though I have no idea whether the "gauge-natural bundles" in question actually encompass all the bundles you care about. Might be a good lead if you're not already aware of it?